# return a set of counts of values in a column by ID

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I have a table like this:

```
ID    Type
----------
1     sent
1     sent
1     open
1     bounce
1     click
2     sent
2     sent
2     open
2     open
2     click
```

I want a query to return results like this:

```
ID    sent    open    bounce    click
1     2       1       1         1
2     2       2       0         1
```

Just can't work out how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try PIVOT

```
SELECT ID,[sent],[open],[bounce],[click]
FROM   your_table
PIVOT (COUNT([Type]) 
FOR   [Type] in ([sent],[open],[bounce],[click]))p
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7ed9/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can get such result by using `PIVOT` or `GROUP BY`, you can even get results if you have variable values in `Type` column:

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #t(ID    INT, Type VARCHAR(100))
INSERT #t 
VALUES 
(1,     'sent'),
(1,     'sent'),
(1,     'open'),
(1,     'bounce'),
(1,     'click'),
(2,     'sent'),
(2,     'sent'),
(2,     'open'),
(2,     'open'),
(2,     'click')
```

`PIVOT` approach:

```
SELECT  pvt.*
FROM    #t
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(Type) FOR Type IN ([sent], [open], [bounce], [click])
) pvt
```

If there are other possible values for `Type` and you don't know them in advance use dynamic `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(1000) = STUFF(
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT ',[' + Type + ']'
    FROM    #t
    FOR     XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(2000) = 
'
SELECT  pvt.*
FROM    #t
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(Type) FOR Type IN ('+@cols+')
) pvt   
'

EXEC(@query)
```

If you have known fixed values for `Type`, you can also use:

```
SELECT  ID,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'sent' THEN 1 END) [sent],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'open' THEN 1 END) [open],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'bounce' THEN 1 END) bounce,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'click' THEN 1 END) click
FROM    #t
GROUP   BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Id, 
count(case When type='sent' then 1 else 0 end) as sent,
count(case when type='open' then 1 else 0 end) as open
From table
Group by Id
```

If that won't give you the exact answer then try count (distinct case....) :)